# &#34; appears when try to pass to jinja2/javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, jinja2

I am reading from Google App Engine from model string property

```
name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

and I am trying to sum by name in dictionary  like

```
def _sum_by_name(self, data):
    result = {}
    for d in data:
        if d.name is not None:
            result[d.name] = result.get(d.name, 0) + 1
    return json.dumps(result)
```

data is fetched result from query and it works, when I pass that to Jinja2 template and try to read in Javascript I am getting around names `&#34;` and I cannot convert that to dictionary in Javascript. Does anyone know problem ?

Comment: What do you find when you search for HTML entity 34?

Answer (score 0):

`&#34` is the HTML entity code for double quotes, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp)

You'll have to use a parser to translate it:

```
import html.parser
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = parser.unescape(string)
```

Result:

```
>>> unescaped
'"'
```

That was for Python 3.x. In Python 2.x, the library is called `HTMLParser`:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
```